# Get The Index Of Ul

Tags: jquery, html, css

There two `Ul` tag on my page . 
this is my code

HtML:

```
<div id="accordion">
   <h3>Funeral</h3>
   <div>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="radio" name="rbPlanname" class="rbPlanname" /> Funeral Plan 1</li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="rbPlanname" class="rbPlanname" /> Funeral Plan 2</li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="rbPlanname" class="rbPlanname" /> Funeral Plan 3</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <h3>Disability</h3>
   <div>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="radio" name="rbPlanname" class="rbPlanname" /> Disability Plan 1</li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="rbPlanname" class="rbPlanname" /> Disability Plan 2</li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="rbPlanname" class="rbPlanname" /> Disability Plan 3</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
 <table width="100%" style="margin-top:26px">
```

JS:

```
 var planName;
 $('#btnNextClaim').on('click', function () {
   $('.rbPlanname').each(function () {
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         planName = $(this).closest('li').text();
         alert($(this).closest('ul').index());
       }
   });
 });
```

i want , when user click on next button , then i'm finding which radio button is checked, according to that , i want to find the index of ul.
let suppose i radio button from first ul is checked , then it should return 0.
here is my fiddle

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/5awT9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('#btnNextClaim').on('click', function () {
         $('.rbPlanname').each(function () {
         if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
             planName = $(this).closest('li').text();
             var $ul=$(this).closest('ul');
             alert($('ul').index($ul));
         }
     });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5awT9/6/)

### EDIT-Caching $(this):

We should cache the DOM element,if used frequently in our code:

```
$('#btnNextClaim').on('click', function () {
    $('.rbPlanname').each(function () {
        var $this=$(this);
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            planName = $this.closest('li').text();
            var $ul=$this.closest('ul');
            alert($('ul').index($ul));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: but why you are passing $ul to index method. can you explain me please.

Comment: index method need the argument(of which element index it will return)
see http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: i'll. i'm just reviewing your code.what if i want to find index of ul only in accordian div.i don't want to count those ul which is outside of accordian.

Comment: Simple update alert($('#accordion ul').index($ul));
see here http://jsfiddle.net/5awT9/12/

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `index()` method what kind of index are you looking for. In your case it should be `ul`

See this http://jsfiddle.net/5awT9/3